# Create table in dynamoDb gives yml syntax error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, yaml

Isn't `LocalSecondaryIndexes` an array? I tried alot of different version of it. With and without a `-`, indenting lines/props. But I can't get it to work.
This syntax gives me `Expected params.LocalSecondaryIndexes to be an Array`.

```
CoordinatesTable:
  Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
  Properties:
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: hashKey
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: rangeKey
        KeyType: RANGE
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: hashKey
        AttributeType: "N"
      - AttributeName: rangeKey
        AttributeType: "S"
      - AttributeName: geohash
        AttributeType: "N"
    LocalSecondaryIndexes:
      IndexName: geohash-index
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: hashKey
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: geohash
          KeyType: RANGE
      Projection: 
        ProjectionType: All
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 10
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    TableName: CoordinatesTable
```

This is the table in json, take from a github projekt.

```
{
  TableName: config.tableName,
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 5
  },
  KeySchema: [
    {
      KeyType: "HASH",
      AttributeName: config.hashKeyAttributeName
    },
    {
      KeyType: "RANGE",
      AttributeName: config.rangeKeyAttributeName
    }
  ],
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: config.hashKeyAttributeName, AttributeType: 'N' },
    { AttributeName: config.rangeKeyAttributeName, AttributeType: 'S' },
    { AttributeName: config.geohashAttributeName, AttributeType: 'N' }
  ],
  LocalSecondaryIndexes: [
    {
      IndexName: config.geohashIndexName,
      KeySchema: [
        {
          KeyType: 'HASH',
          AttributeName: config.hashKeyAttributeName
        },
        {
          KeyType: 'RANGE',
          AttributeName: config.geohashAttributeName
        }
      ],
      Projection: {
        ProjectionType: 'ALL'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

}
}

Comment: Why a negative vote? I don't care about it but it's good to know why...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error message is misleading and should rather state that `LocalSecondaryIndexes` should be a list, because that's what it is in the JSON representation. So making a list out of it in YAML should work fine:

```
LocalSecondaryIndexes:
  - IndexName: geohash-index
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: hashKey
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: geohash
        KeyType: RANGE
    Projection: 
      ProjectionType: All
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I only needed to change ProjectionType: All to uppercase ProjectionType: ALL